# Convert Series to float data in python pandas

Tags: pandas

I have written code to find maximum value horizontally. Now I want to store it to other location in data frame using .iloc[] function. I am not able to do it as dtype of it is series. How to convert series to float value?

Code:

```
master = pd.read_csv("new.csv")
a = master.iloc[:, 154:181].max(axis=1)
print(type(b))
b = pd.to_numeric(a, downcast='integer')
print(type(b))
master.to_csv(new, index=False)
```

Output:

```
class 'pandas.core.series.Series'
class 'pandas.core.series.Series'
```

I want to convert Series to float data type so that I can store it in other location. Another location is master.iloc[0,182] = a

Comment: `Now I want to store it to other location in data frame`  What other location?

Comment: If you don't want `b` converted to float, don't use `downcast='integer'`.

Comment: @COLDSPEED I have edited a post.

Comment: That's incorrect. The slice's size must be the same as `b`.

Comment: By finding maximum value using a = master.iloc[:, 154:181].max(axis=1), gives series dtype. how to convert that into float?

Comment: So you'll have a series of size `len(df)`. To convert to float, use `a = a.astype(float)`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I'm guessing that you want to take the maximum of a row and add all of the row-wise maxima as a new column.  Is that correct?  If so, can you clarify your question and add a minimum example?  If that's the case, `df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,20,3], 'b':[10,2,3], 'c':[1,2,30]});
df['biggest'] = df.max(axis='columns')` will do it in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I got the Answer. I am converting Series to String by using command a.to_string(). This will convert a value of "a" from series dtype to String dtype. Using string to float conversion, I am finally getting Float value.

```
master = pd.read_csv("new.csv")
a = master.iloc[:, 154:181].max(axis=1)
b = a.to_string()
#print(type(b))
master.ix[0,181] = float(b)
master.to_csv(new, index=False)
```